# Will a phenom x6 Thuban fit in a K10N78M Pro?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, am3

TL;DR

Will a phenom x6 Thuban fit in a K10N78M Pro?
Or
Will an AM2+ socket with AM3 support, yet doesn't list the specific model CPU support it as long as very similar models are also stated as supported?

> CPU list
>   http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/K10N78M%20Pro/?cat=CPU
>
> Example point of sale (though I already have the part and not for a gorllion dollars)
>   http://www.pcupgrade.co.uk/productdetails.asp?ProductID=9228&categoryid=562

Basically I need to know if this part will work in that motherboard. If you can help me then I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Verify they are both the same socket, if thats the case, provided you use the most current revision of the BIOS it should work.  The motherboard in question supports both AM3 and AM2+ CPUs.  Besides the CPU is listed on that list `HDT55TWFK6DGR` the two part numbers while different indicate the same part.  **HDT55T**WFK6DGR **HDT75T**FBGRBOX one is a retail produdt the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

check socket compatibility and if the socket / cpu had the same amount of pins, if they're a match and both fits without any issue, install them and update the bios to latest version to ensure maximun compatibility